# Magento 2 Get Request Param Always Null

Tags: magento2, collection, uicomponent, data-provider

I can't seem to get request params from a Data Provider. I've modified `Magento\Review\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ReviewDataProvider.php` to log (also tried var_dump) the information, but it always returns null.

The following code is from `Magento\Review\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ReviewDataProvider.php`,

```
   public function getData()
    {

        $this->getCollection()->addEntityFilter($this->request->getParam('current_product_id', 0))
            ->addStoreData();

        $arrItems = [
            'totalRecords' => $this->getCollection()->getSize(),
            'items' => [],
        ];

        foreach ($this->getCollection() as $item) {
            $arrItems['items'][] = $item->toArray([]);
        }

        return $arrItems;
    }
```

If I try to var_dump or log `$this->request->getParam('current_product_id', 0)`, the result is null. This is the only point for the Collection to be filtered by the product ID (that I've found). 
I've also tried `$this->getCollection()->getParams()`, which shows some parameters, but the `current_product_id` is not included.
Why does this happen and how can I view the request parameter?

Comment: Did you solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

In the ***`function getData()`*** in Magento\Review\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ReviewDataProvider.php is called by Magento 2 times.
The first call is made by GET to **`{{domain_admin}}/mui/index/render/?namespace=review_listing&isAjax=true`**,
in which only ***`$this->request->getParams()`*** the namespace variable and isAjax appear.
And in the **second call is made by POST** and receives more parameters. Among them, the **current_product_id**